# Date Repeat: Display only the first and last instances of a series?

Tags: 6, datetime

I have been going crazy trying to find a way to display only the first and last dates of a series using Date Repeat, either in a view or the node itself, of repeating events.  For example, there is a course that starts on January 16, and repeats every Monday until March 5.  I would like to be able to display something like "Every Monday from January 16 until March 5" or something to that effect.  Does anyone have any advice, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I thought I'd put in my two cents.

The only way I can think to accomplish this is with custom PHP and a call to the database. You could collect all of the dates for an event an then just show the first and last. The name of the repeat rule is saved in the `field_date_rrule` column and could be parsed from there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what it's like in 6, but in 7 (with Views 3.x) you can just toggle the Repeat rule select and choose "Show repeat rule" on the field that contains your date.  If you don't like the date display, you can create a custom one by going to admin/config/regional/date-time and modifying the formats and types.